# Not able to set value to property

Tags: c#, xml

Here what's I am doing.

- Read XML File
- Map fields in Data Contracts using XMLSerializer
- Perform Some Operation and Update the Values in Same Data Contract Class

[XmlType("RepaymentSchedule")]

```
[XmlType("RepaymentSchedule")]    
public class APIRepaymentSchedule
{
    [XmlArray("ItemList")]
    public List<APIRepaymentScheduleDetails> RepaymentScheduleDetails;          
} 

[XmlType("RepaymentScheduleDetails")]
public class APIRepaymentScheduleDetails
{
    public Decimal? EscrowPayment { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Payment")]
    public string _Payment { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public Decimal? Payment 
    {
        get
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_Payment))
                return Decimal.Parse(_Payment);
            return null;
        }
        set { }
    }
}
```

De-Serailize XML:

```
public static APIOutstandingResponseDetail ParseGetOutstandingXML(string custxml)
{
    APIOutstandingResponseDetail OutstandingDetails;
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(APIOutstandingResponseDetail), new XmlRootAttribute("OutstandingResponseDetail"));
    using (TextReader rdr = new StringReader(custxml))
    {
        OutstandingDetails = (APIOutstandingResponseDetail)serializer.Deserialize(rdr);
    }
    return OutstandingDetails;
}
```

`APIRepaymentSchedule` is part of `APIOutstandingResponseDetail`

I am able to read all XML field values into class variables.

**Here is question:**

I am doing some calculation on one of the fields. Let's say `Payment`. I want to set a value of Payment after reading the XML files.

```
var responseObj = new APIRepaymentSchedule();
responseObj.RepaymentScheduleDetails[index].Payment = /* Set Some Value Here*/;
```

- *Why am I not able to set the value to `Payment` field here? Any idea. It retains its old value from XML.*

I tried:

```
set { Payment = value; }
```

It gives StackOverflow Exception

Comment: Because the set-part of the property is empty and does nothing?

Comment: I tried setting the value it gives me exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your setter of Payment property to someone which will set it, for example this:

```
set { 
    _Payment= value.ToString();
}
```

Comment: It will set for `_Payment` right. How I can assign it to `Payment`

Comment: @Shaggy Your Payment property getter is set to return _Payment if it has value, so when you set _Payment you set Payment too